# Sequential sampling on point clouds returning the same indices

Tags: c++, random, point-cloud-library

I am writing a ransac implementation for use with point clouds, I am aware `pcl` also has some but my needs are a bit more specific and writing a custom model in the `pcl` style didn't seem very clear.

For this purpose I need to uniformly sample points from the point cloud without replacement, for this purpose I figured I should use `pcl::RandomSample`. However, applying this sequentially, example:

```cpp
pcl::RandomSample<pcl::PointXYZRGB> sample(false);
sample.setInputCloud(cloud);
sample.setSample(5);

pcl::Indices indices;
sample.filter(indices);
for (auto &i : indices) {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "==========" << std::endl;

indices.clear();
sample.filter(indices);
for (auto &i : indices) {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

results in the same indices, which isn't particularly random. What could I be doing wrong?

**Edit**: With a randomly generated point cloud of 500 elements, the return of the above code, in one case, was

```cpp
42
145
195
196
290
==========
42
145
195
196
290
```

Comment: I never used the library, but most random stuff needs some initialization.  https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_random_sample.html has a setSeed method. And this code calls it : https://gist.github.com/Kyungpyo-Kim/02368d331ad812bad7801d3a7f2a05c4 So I think that's what you're missing

Comment: The seed gets set automatically in the constructor, in addition the calls above are able to return random indices which change every run.

Comment: The problem is that in the code section I posted, despite calling `sample.filter(indices)` twice the printed indices are the same.

Comment: @MortenNissov You have to call `setSeed()` with a seed if you want to get different random values.